# always use 24-hour format

Tags: ios, nsdate

I am capturing date in 24-hour format, on devices that are configured with 24 hour works fine but if the device has added the 12 o'clock I am or pm and does not serve me well.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"ddMMYYYYHHmmss"];
NSDate *hoy = [NSDate date];
NSString *fecha = [format stringFromDate:hoy];
[defaults setObject:fecha forKey:@"ValorHoy"];
[defaults synchronize];
NSDate *fechaGuardada = (NSDate*)[defaults objectForKey:@"ValorHoy"];
```

I always need to generate the date in this format ddMMyyyyHHmmss - (010220141405) on some devices but I get so (010220141405 pm) does not serve me, not recognized by the server, as the am or pm off forever no matter the time format device.

Comment: `010220141405 pm` is a really strange format since it has both 24 hours (14 > 12) and "pm" in it. Is that actual output or a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an `NSDate` from that `NSString` again, you can just force it to be an `NSDate`.

Use `NSDateFormatter` to convert from `NSDate` to `NSString` and vica versa.

Also keep in mind that initializing an `NSDateFormatter` is expensive, so if you use it a lot if time (like parsing a lot of data from/to server) than use an cache one formatter for every format.

Don't crate `NSDateFormatter` in a every loop with the same format.

```
// Replace this
NSDate *fechaGuardada = (NSDate*)[defaults objectForKey:@"ValorHoy"];

// With this
NSDate *fechaGuardada = [format dateFromString:[defaults objectForKey:@"ValorHoy"]];
```

Comment: thanks but that change does not work now generates me a date "2014-04-05 12:13:23 p.m." and I need to always be "20140405121323"